# Supporting iPad Mini when I need more RAM

Tags: ios, ipad, ipad-mini

I'm developing a game that requires a decent amount of memory. I've optimized it for basically every iOS device that can run 8.0+, except for the iPads with 512MB of RAM. Do I have to support the iPad mini, or could I write a disclaimer stating that it won't run that device. Or is there some way that I can half the size of every image that is loaded by code? What is the best way to go about this?